# Are many-to-many relationships possible with enums in JPA or Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, enums, many-to-many

My question is basically the title, and the text below describes my attempt to make it work. So, is what I'm trying to achieve possible or should I create a `Category` class instead and do conversions between the enum and the entity?

`Article` has a many-to-many relationship to `Category`, but `Category` is an enum and is causing troubles. JPA creates the tables well, but when I query for a category, this exception is thrown:

JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity: Category.

I do have a constructor but a constructor of an enum can only be private, and the JPA specification states that the default constructor of an entity should be public or protected.

The Category Enum:

```
@Entity
public enum Category {

    HOME_NEWS("home news"),
    FOREIGN_NEWS("foreign news"),
    POLITICS("politics"),
    BUSINESS("business"),
    BREAKING("breaking"), // and updates
    SCIENCE("science"),
    OPINION("opinion"),
    SPORTS("sports"),
    ENVIRONMENT("environment"),
    TECHNOLOGY("technology"),
    TRAVEL("travel"),
    FASHION("fashion"),
    LIFESTYLE("lifestyle"),
    HEALTH("health"),
    ARTS("arts"),
    FOOD("food"),
    CULTURE("culture"),
    GLAMOUR("glamour"),
    PHOTOGRAPHY("photography"),
    NOT_DEFINED("not defined");

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    Category() {
    }

    Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private static Map<String, Category> nameToValueMap = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for (Category category : EnumSet.allOf(Category.class)) {
            nameToValueMap.put(category.name(), category);
        }
    }

    public static Category forName(String name) {
        return nameToValueMap.get(name);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

And the partial Article class:

```
@Entity
public class Article implements Comparable<Article> {

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "article_category",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "article_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")})
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>(0);
}
```